# Apache current live settings

Tags: apache-2.4

You know in postfix (I'm using Ubuntu 14) you can get all the current config settings by doing a postconf

Is there a way to see *all* the live config settings of Apache?

I can do a phpinfo(); but that shows all php information and a very small set of apache information.

Any ideas?

** SORTED **

Enable mod_info by doing a "a2enmod info" and edit the conf file accordingly

`<Location /server-info>
   SetHandler server-info
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 1.2.3.4 # your IP, subnet, whatever
</Location>`

Then go to http://myserver/server-info following an Apache restart

More information on the mod_info can be found at, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html